# Bringing field from class sale.order to account.invoice class

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I need help with bringing the `job_title_2` field data from class `sale.order` to `account.invoice` based on the record from `job_title`.

```
class SaleOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    job_title = fields.Char('Job Title')
    job_title_2 = fields.Char('Job Title 2')
```

```
class InvoiceLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'
    
    job_title = fields.Char('Job Title')
    job_title_2 = fields.Char('Job Title 2')
```

I tried using but not working

```
@api.depends('sale_order_id')
def get_order(self):
    if self.sale_order_id:
        self.job_title_2= self.sale_order_id.job_title_2
```

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You didn't show us how you used the API or any of the imported modules.

Comment: A sale order can be related to many invoices, you can check the [sale](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/addons/sale/models/sale.py#L160) module source code

Comment: @sanitizedUser sorry, now i already edit the code of api.depends

Answer (score 2):

The `get_order` method will not be triggered and the value of `job_title_2` will not change. To use a computed method, you need to set the [compute](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/orm.html#computed-fields) parameter on the `job_title_2` field.

***Example:***

```
job_title_2 = fields.Char(compute="get_order")
```

*The `account.invoice` model must have a `sale_order_id` field*

If you want to bring fields from the sale order to the account invoice, you can override the sale order [_prepare_invoice](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/addons/sale/models/sale.py#L357-L386) method and add your field values

***Example:***

```
@api.multi
def _prepare_invoice(self):
    res = super(SaleOrderLine, self)._prepare_invoice()
    res['job_title'] = self.job_title
    res['job_title_2'] = self.job_title_2
    return res
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to create your desired field in `account.invoice`
which I think you already have.

Second there is a method in `sale.order` which is responsible for creating an invoice and sending data from sales order to the invoice. Just override this method.

```py
class SaleOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    job_title = fields.Char('Job Title')
    job_title_2 = fields.Char('Job Title 2')

    @api.multi
    def _prepare_invoice(self):
        res = super(SaleOrderLine, self)._prepare_invoice()
        res.update({
            'job_title_2': self.job_title_2
            'job_title': self.job_title
        })
        return res
```